# If the resolvent $(\lambda - A)^{-1}$ is compact, then is $A$ Fredholm of index $0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be an operator on a Banach space, possibly unbounded,
such that its resolvent $(\lambda - A)^{-1}$ is compact.
Is $A$ then a Fredholm operator of index 0? 
My feeling is yes but I cannot prove it.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why do you feel this should be true in the case where $A$ is bounded? My *feeling* is that your question would make more sense if $A$ is densely-defined, closed and unbounded -- is that the particular case you had in mind

Comment: Also, I don't know what it means for an unbounded densely-defined operator to be Fredholm. What was the definition you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$ (\lambda - A)^{-1}(\lambda - A) = 1 \quad \quad \quad (\lambda - A)(\lambda - A)^{-1} = 1 $$
These equations give rise to the equations
$$ \lambda(\lambda-A)^{-1} = 1 - (A - \lambda)^{-1} A $$
and
$$ \lambda(\lambda-A)^{-1} = 1 - A(A - \lambda)^{-1} $$
Since $(\lambda-A)^{-1}$ is compact so is $\lambda(\lambda-A)^{-1}$. Therefore $A$ is invertible modulo the compact operators and thus equivalently Fredholm.